# Zabbix item - amount of data transfered per day and week

Tags: zabbix

Good day. Using net.if.in and net.if.out keys I'm getting total amount of bytes transferred through a network interface. If I store value as delta I'll get speed per second. Is there a way to get amount of data transfered each day and week? Thank you in advance. Vojta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use [calculated items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated) and sum a month worth of seconds back. But it will give you the last month only. Or you can count the week's worth of bytes [every Monday](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/time_period) and then sum these up every 4 Mondays back but it is also not the best way. This is what I can offer from zabbix side. What I would do would be to create an external script croned for every 1st of a month that sums the values directly from database and updates an item in zabbix with the result. Or if you are brave enough you can dig into the API and do a JSON call to select items a month back every 1st of the month and loop over to sum, then update an item using a zabbix sender of your preference.